# private key problem

Tags: iphone, certificate, ssl-certificate, push, push-notification

my problem is when i double click on aps_developer_identity.cer the private key didn't appear and i need it to export to .p12

im really confused is there any solution

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The private key is created when the identity request is made.  I don't believe it is in the .cer file you download from dev portal.

Comment: recently when i open the test.cer it appear in key chain with a little arrow in the left when i click it the private key appear but now no arrow so...

Comment: The private key is ONLY in the computer which generated the certificate request. It is named to email address used for requesting, that's what you should looking for in keychain.